# How do I code paperjs key.isDown() combos

Tags: paperjs

How do I handle <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> key for uppercase or option?

`a` could be any key like `1` or `!` 
`/` or `?`

or

`h` or <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to get H with the uppercase.

I'm trying to build a WYSIWYG with Paper.js.

When I double click into a text item I want to be able to change the text. I have that working, but if I hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to get `A` I get `shifta`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Characters such as `!@#$%^&*()_+` etc. should be handled properly by `onKeyDown`. To handle uppercase letters, check to see if the shift-modifier is active:

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key == 'shift' || event.key == 'command' || event.key == 'option' || event.key == 'caps-lock' || event.key == 'control') return;
    if (event.modifiers.shift || event.modifiers.capsLock) {
        console.log('The ' + event.key.toUpperCase() + ' key was pressed!');
    }    
    else console.log('The ' + event.key + ' key was pressed!');
}
```

Comment: This helped me out a lot. Here is my code with space and backspace

Answer (score 0):

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key == 'shift' || event.key == 'command' || event.key == 'option' || event.key == 'caps-lock' || event.key == 'control') return;


    if (event.modifiers.shift || event.modifiers.capsLock) {
        text.content = text.content + event.key.toUpperCase();
    }else if (Key.isDown('space')){
        event.preventDefault();
        text.content = text.content + " ";
    }else if (Key.isDown('backspace')){
        var subStr = text.content.substring(0, text.content.length - 1)
        text.content = subStr;
    }    
    else{
        text.content = text.content + event.key;
    } 
}
```

This is what I ended up with.